# How to see the results of my first module

Tags: views, 7

I created a module to alter the query executed by a view, but i cannot figure it out how to test it ...  I mean where should i see the results ?
I've created the following files:

```
my_module.info
my_module.module
my_module.views.inc
```

in the second file i have:

```
function my_module_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3, 
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module'), 
    'template path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module'),
  );
}
```

and in the third one:

```
function my_module_hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)  {
  var_dump($view);
}
```

Where should i be able to see the result of var_dump ?

Comment: Have you created any Views ? Views alter will be invoked whenever a view is rendered in front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[hook_views_query_alter()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) is supposed to alter the query passed as second parameter, or the view object passed as first argument, not to output anything. If you want to debug the hook, you should use code similar to the following one.

```
watchdog('my_module', 'View: @view', array('@view' => print_r($view, TRUE)), WATCHDOG_DEBUG);
```

The name you gave to your hook is wrong: You just need to replace hook with the short name of your module. For a hook like `hook_views_query_alter()`, the function name is not `my_module_hook_views_query_alter()`, but `my_module_views_query_alter()`.

Comment: Good spot... :)

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere probably, you're dumping the var straight out to the buffer which isn't the 'done thing' in Drupal :) (unless you're taking care of the page rendering yourself for whatever reason, but that's a different story)

For debugging, get a copy of the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and use the excellent `dpm()` function like so:

```
function my_module_hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  dpm($view);
}
```

That'll give you a nice output to the message area similar to:

[image]

You can navigate through and drill down into expandable variables...all in all it makes debugging simple arrays and objects very easy.

Comment: i see .. i wrote var_dump just as an example ... I've changed to dsm , where should i go to see the result as the picture you provided?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your hook name is wrong. It should be `my_module_views_query_alter()` instead of `my_module_hook_views_query_alter()` ( kiamlaluno has mentioned )
Assuming you have a view and its machine name is "my_view" and its menu path is "example/myview".
The `var_dump` result will be rendered in the page http://yousite.com/example/myview

In the hook, you may alter the query of the view by checking its view name, for example

```
function my_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  var_dump($view);  // this will be displayed in all views pages
  switch($view->name){
    case 'my_view' :    // this is machine name of the view
      // query alter here
      var_dump($view);  // this will be displayed only in this view page, for example, http://yousite.com/example/myview
    break;

    case 'another_view' :

    break;
  }
}
```